# Is it possible to jump to a specific iteration of a loop when debugging?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, loops, iteration

In Xcode, if I have a for loop that either has a hardcoded limit (i.e. only goes up to 100), is it possible to jump to a specific iteration of the loop? For example, say I have the following loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {

    [someObject doSomething];
}
```

If I put a breakpoint before the for loop declaration line, can I somehow go to the 42nd iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- One way is to set a breakpoint inside the loop, then do a right click on it and select *Edit Breakpoint...* In the field called *Condition* you can write something like `i == 50` which means it will stop the first time `i` equals to `50`
- Second way is to set a breakpoint before entering the loop, run the program, place your cursor above the `i`-Variable and change its value in the third field of the yellow pop-up

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Note that editing the value of the loop variable in fact changes the variable directly. It does not run the earlier iterations of your loop.